# Update only the greatest row - Sequential Based Update

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-update

I want to write a query to find the LOWEST SEQUENCE for status = REQUEST_PENDING then update it after a certain condition.

For example:

| person_name | status | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | request_progressed | 1 |
| b | request_pending | 2 |
| c | request_pending | 3 |

If the person named A is done, it's status would change from "request_progressed" to "request_done"; then the next person B will have his status changed to "request_progressed" while the person C stays the same because its sequence is the 3rd.

So I just need to know how do I change the person B status by finding the lowest sequence which has "request_pending" status and THERE IS (SUPPOSED TO BE) ONLY ONE "request_progressed" on the table that is why when it is updated to "request_done" the next "request_pending" need to be updated to "request_progressed".

I tried the following:

```
update table
set status = 'request_progressed'
where status = 'pending' AND sequence = min(sequence)
```

Comment: This would really benefit from proper sample data and expected results, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How do you order the data in the first place? What determines if person b appears before person c and not the other way round?

Comment: Query cannot. Trigger cannot too. The task may be solved in stored procedure format.

Comment: *I want to write a query to find the LOWEST SEQUENCE AND REQUEST_PENDING STATUS then update it after a certain condition.* Does this means that (1) `column_status` may have one of 3 values - `'request_pending', 'request_progressed', 'request_done'`; (2) only one row (not more and not none) in the table may have the value `'request_progressed'` at any moment?

Comment: @Akina yes, only one request_progressed, I will edit it

Comment: @SalmanA Let's say, IF the person C "SEQUENCE" is 2 and the person B "SEQUENCE" is 3, then the person C status is updated to "request_progressed" while the person B stays the same, it is all about sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL - you can specify order by and limit in update queries:

```sql
update t
set status = 'request_progressed'
where status = 'request_pending'
order by sequence
limit 1
```

In PostgreSQL - you still need order by and limit but they can only be used inside a subquery:

```
update t
set status = 'request_progressed'
where (status, sequence) in (
    select status, sequence
    from t
    where status = 'request_pending'
    order by sequence
    offset 0 rows fetch first 1 row only
)
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer. However, it gives error like this -> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "order"

Comment: Is this mysql or something else?